# Stop .load from loading

Tags: jquery

I have a file which loads content from another file on document.ready and I have a link which loads different content into the same container. I want to stop .load on document ready when hyperlink is being clicked?

Comment: jQuery doesn't seem to expose the ajax request of `.load` calls. The best you can do is using `$.ajax` and appending manually, and `.abort()`ing the xhr.

Answer (score 0):

Make a conditional that checks for link event is fired, then

```
 .abort();
```

to kill the function